# how to deploy a helm chart a 2nd time

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I need to deploy the ingress-nginx helm chart twice, once for private and once for public services. The chart for private ingresses is already deployed, in namespace=kube-system and with  release-name=nginx-ingress-private.

When I run the installation command I get this error that indicates a conflict with the installed version for private ingress:

> george@devops:~/ $ helm -n ingress-nginx-public install
> ingress-nginx-public ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
> Error: INSTALLATION
> FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
> Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace ""
> exists and cannot be imported into the current release:  invalid
> ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key
> "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "ingress-nginx-public": current
> value is "nginx-ingress-private"; annotation validation error: key
> "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "ingress-nginx-public":
> current value is "kube-system"

I have seen a chart deployed twice on the same cluster so I know it's possible.

Thanks for any help.